# Perl URIencodes non-latin characters

Tags: perl, post

I use perl for ajax (POST method), and when I read POST query with script below, I get my query URIencoded.

Example: sent - привет , received: %D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82

Latin queries work well. Script was just googled somewhere.

Script:

```
sub populatePostFields {
    %_POST = ();
    read( STDIN, $tmpStr, $ENV{ "CONTENT_LENGTH" } );
    @parts = split( /\&/, $tmpStr );
    foreach $part (@parts) {
        ( $name, $value ) = split( /\=/, $part );
        $value =~ ( s/%23/\#/g );
        $value =~ ( s/%2F/\//g );
        $_POST{ "$name" } = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, and? What's the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's not Perl-specific. The web browser is required to URI-encode the values when sending.

You can use the standard `use CGI` module to decode form fields for you — this is definitely recommended, as it will take care of all kinds of edge cases for you, and is also usable if you decide to convert to a `mod_perl` module later.

If you're running a CGI script, I also *strongly* recommend that you have `-T` on the `shebang` line (`#!/usr/bin/perl -T`) and `use strict;`, to help catch things that might otherwise be easily exploitable over the web.

```
     #!/usr/bin/perl -T
     use strict;
     use CGI;

     my $q = CGI->new;

     print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";

     print "<html><body><h1> Field FOO contains: ", $q->param('FOO'),
           "</h1></body></html>\n\n";
```

→

```
     <html><body><h1> Field FOO contains: привет </h1></body></html>
```

You can use the `->param(`*string*`)` to read the various form fields; it'll handle GET and POST transparently, and decode the URI-encoded strings for you.

The "not-recommended, hard way" would be to use the expression:

```
       my ($name, $value) = split /\=/, $part;
       $value =~ s/\+/ /g;
       $value =~ s/(\%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F])/ (chr (hex $1)) /gex;
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped, but I have one more question: it works right if I use print(), but die() returns page in iso-5589 charset. Can encoding of die() be set?

Comment: untested, but I *believe* you can do two things; first, make sure your header has `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`; and secondly, set `binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';` … depending on your `die` handler, the results might vary. (See CPAN's `CGI::Carp` for a nice way to dump exceptions to the browser)